# Copy area of an image into transparent area on same image

Tags: gimp

I would like to copy an area into a transparent area in the same image using GIMP.

I have drawn a rectangle around the area that I want to copy, then I select "Edit" -> "Copy visible".

Then I clear the selection by left-clicking somewhere else on the image.

Then I draw another rectangle where I want to paste the copied area and select "Edit" -> "Paste".

What I get is a half-transparent output instead of an opaque.

How could I make the pasted area fully opaque?

Thank you!

This is the original image:

[image]

And this is the output:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You don't need `Copy visible`, `Copy` is enough for this purpose
2. you don't need to clear the selection after the copy
3. you don't need to make a selection on the target

The usual procedure is:

- Make a selection
- Edit>Copy (Ctrl-C)
- (optional) Select a target layer
- Edit>Paste (Ctrl-V). This creates a "Floating selection" layer
- You move that layer where you want with the Move tool (you can also apply other transforms)
- You either make a new layer (Ctrl-Shift-N) from the floating selection, or merge it ("anchor" it) in the active layer (Ctrl-H).

Without seeing your Layers list in the screen shot it is difficult to tell what is happening (partial opacity? layer mode not `Normal`?). What surprises me is that your Red channel isn't selected in the Channels list (this explains the green tint).